# So many problems trying to get Hyper V working with Ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, display-resolution, hyper-v

I have created a hyper-v virtual machine and with Unbuntu running on it. Originally I went with Unbuntu ubuntu 20.04. But I could not resize it or set up a shared folder.
I followed the instructions setting resolution via the etc/default/grub file, did not work

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
```

Then

```
 sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Did not work, then i tried to to set Enhanced Session

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools
cd linux-vm-tools/ubuntu/18.04
./install.sh
```

The install ran, i rebooted in powershell in admin I ran the following

```
Set-VM -VMName UbuntuVM -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket
```

Restarted by Hyper-v, EnhancedSession was still grayed out.
So I gave up on 20.04 and downloaded 18.04.3 LTS

It works in that it gives me a EnhancedSession I can resize the screen. But the  icons are tiny. I right clicked in the top right. It brings up a window. I select the crossed spanners , select spanners select dock and increase the size to max but the icons are still very small.

I want to stick with 18.04.3 LTS it gives me everything but icon size.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 is quite outdated, and [18.04.6](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) is recommended if the machine will be connected to the Internet in any fashion. 18.04 also has just a year or so of support left, meaning that you may need to go through this exercise again next spring if these systems need to receive security updates. What is the ultimate goal you are trying to address? With a better understanding, it may be possible to offer a longer-term solution 

Comment: I use Hyper VM and it only has 18.04.3 LTS and 20.04.. 
All I want to do is have a simple HyperVM virtual machine running, One where I can copy and paste and use shared folders, .. So I can take files of my windows and put them on the HyperVM, one where I can resize the screen
The goal is just to have a HyperVM on my windows that runs Ubuntu, that I can develop code on.
I work for a company that developed all its code on linux, works only on linux, and has decided to not issue anymore macs.
If I cant hyper V working, I am going back to trying to get Oracle VM running.

Comment: VirtualBox is *much* easier in my experience. Better driver support, too. If you don’t mind using that as the VM engine, it’ll save you a bunch of hassle 

Comment: Yup I have got virtual box running.It is a lot easier to set up  Now i am having problems with docker. But that is for another stackover flow. Few years to go to retirement, then I will never again bang my head, trying to get multiple moving parts all of different versions running together

Comment: @matigo Is it more reliable than Hyper-V?  I have constant issues with the network being unreliable when Hyper-V is running.

Comment: @Michael if you install VirtualBox via the Ubuntu repositories, then it’s rock solid. If you install VirtualBox via the .deb file from Oracle, it’s hit and miss. Virtual machine software is highly dependent on the stability of the base OS, the hardware, the firmware, and which microcode is installed in the CPU. That said, installing from the Ubuntu repositories tends to provide the most reliable version that is compatible with the version of Ubuntu you’re running 